# Javascript/AJAX taking two clicks

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I'm constructing a log in form that will log me in without refreshing the page.

I have the following page:

```
    INDEX.php

    <script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {

//log in- send data to php page which creates a session. Log in div is reloaded to display log out button.
       $("#login_form").submit(function()
       {
          $.post("php/loginajax.php",{emai:$('#emai').val(),pass:$('#pass').val()} ,function(data)
          {         
             if(data=='yes') {$('#login').load('inc/headerlogin.php');}
             if(data =='no')   {$("#loginerror").show();}                   
          });
          //return false;
       });

//log out- destroy session and reload log in div to display log in form again.
       $("#logout").click(function()
       {
          $.post("php/loginout.php");
          $('#login').load('inc/headerlogin.php');
       });

    });
    </script>
```

Log out button works fine- click it once, session destroyed, login div reloaded to display.

Log in button works if it's on first page load.
If log in, then log out then try to log in again, all on same page without refreshing it takes two clicks of the log in button.

Also I've scattered in some alerts both before the if statements and inside them but even when the rest of the code works these aren't being shown... any ideas?

Comment: The trivial answer would be, on your first click, the POST is not successful, hence the success function is not being called. I.e. problem with your server.

Comment: I hadn't thought of it that way, but when I click on it on a new page it works first time. It's when I log out, then try to log in on the same page without refreshing I have to click twice.

Comment: What is `inc/headerlogin.php` and why do you need to `load()` it again after logout? If that file includes your JS, then the `$(document).ready()` will run again and register a 2nd `submit` handler.

Comment: inc/headerlogin.php just checks if the session has been set (in php/loginajax.php) and will either display the log in form or the log out button through php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Been looking back on my questions, seems I should've been making the actual form live:

```
$("#login_form").live("submit", function(event) { });"
```

Answer (score 1):

if  logout button reloading, i guess u must use live instead of click

```
$("#logout").live('click',function()
   {
      $.post("php/loginout.php");
      $('#login').load('inc/headerlogin.php');
   });
```

I wish this helps you..

Comment: Thank you but the log out button is fine, it is the log in form on a page that I've already logged out of and not refreshed.

Comment: Revisiting my old questions and you were partly right! I should've used "$("#login_form").live("submit", function(event) { });"